# AngularJS - calculate threshold and offset - simple math

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a playlist with some div's that i want to highlight when i scroll down and the div nears the top of the scroll content.

I think it's pretty simple, but can't get it to work right now ..

```
.directive('scrollWatch', [function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

    var offset = 20;            
    var threshold = 190;
    var selected = 1;

    scope.songSelected = selected;

        element.bind('scroll', function(e) {

            if(e.detail.scrollTop > (threshold-offset)) {
                selected = Math.ceil(e.detail.scrollTop / (threshold-offset));
            }else{
                selected = 1;
            }

            scope.songSelected = selected;
            scope.$apply();

        });

    }
};
}])
```

it works perfect with the first one, but the next starts 20px to early and so on ..

my div's are 190 pix height, and i want all to be highlighted 20px before they start.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it should have been:

```
selected = Math.ceil((e.detail.scrollTop+offset) / threshold);
```